# spring statemachine runs unexcpectedly?

Tags: spring-statemachine

I setup a statemachine as follow

```
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachine
public class StateMachineConfig
        extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<States, Events> {

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<States, Events> config)
            throws Exception {
        config
            .withConfiguration()
                .autoStartup(true)
                .listener(listener());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, Events> states)
            throws Exception {
        states
            .withStates()
                .initial(States.START)
                .end(States.END)
                    .states(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(States.GlobalEligibility, States.DeclareService, States.DeployPersonalization)));
    }



    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States, Events> transitions)
            throws Exception {
        transitions
            .withExternal()
                .source(States.START).target(States.GlobalEligibility).event(Events.GlobalEligibility)
                .and()
            .withExternal()
                .source(States.GlobalEligibility).target(States.DeclareService).event(Events.DeclareService)
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .state(States.END)

                ;
    }
```

and I'm using generic message to send event with payload.

```
GenericMessage<Events> ge = new GenericMessage<Events>(Events.GlobalEligibility, headers);
        stateMachine.sendEvent(ge);
```

statmanage is configured as follow

```
@WithStateMachine
public class StateManager
{
@OnTransition(target={"GlobalEligibility"})
    @Transactional
    public void globalEligibilityTransition(@EventHeaders Map<String, Object> headers, ExtendedState extendedState,StateContext<States, Events> stateContext, Exception e)
    {
        log.info("globalEligibilityTransition state");
}
}
```

**after I sent event, it will be executed twice for the first time but after that it won't be executed anymore with the same code.** what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a bug with use of `@Transactional` and issue [#510](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/510) should handle it.